# How can I transform a vector of strings in Rust with map and then join the strings with flat_map in one line?

Tags: rust, iterator, rust-rustlings

I'm doing the [second level](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/main/exercises/18_iterators/iterators2.rs) of rustlings for the iterator chapter.

I found the following solution for step 3, and now I would like to chain map and flat_map.

```
// Step 3.
// Apply the `capitalize_first` function again to a slice of string slices.
// Return a single string.
// ["hello", " ", "world"] -> "Hello World"
pub fn capitalize_words_string(words: &[&str]) -> String {
    let capitalized: Vec<String> = words.iter().map(|word| capitalize_first(&word)).collect();
    capitalized.iter().flat_map(|s| s.chars()).collect()
}
```

However, with this naive approach...

```
words.iter().map(|w| capitalize_first(w)).flat_map(|s| s.char_indices()).collect()
```

I receive these compiler errors, which I don't understand:

```
36   |     words.iter().map(|w| capitalize_first(w)).flat_map(|s| s.char_indices()).collect()
     |                                                                              ^^^^^^^ value of type `String` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=(usize, char)>`
```

```
36   |     words.iter().map(|w| capitalize_first(w)).flat_map(|s| s.char_indices()).collect()
     |     ----- ------ ---------------------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Iterator::Item` changed to `(usize, char)` here
     |     |     |      |
     |     |     |      `Iterator::Item` changed to `String` here
     |     |     `Iterator::Item` is `&&str` here
     |     this expression has type `&[&str]`
```

Comment: I'm confused about your confusion. [`chars()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) produces, `char`s, while [`char_indices()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices) produces indexed chars, i.e. `(usize, char)`. Which is not the same. You can _only_ collect `char`s into `String`. So if it's because you need the index, then you'd need to additionally `.map(|(i, c)| c)` to get rid of it, before `.collect()`ing

Comment: Also you can collect an iterator of Strings straight into a String. No need to turn them into characters.

Comment: @drewtato, yeah, I guess I didn't see the obvious here -.-

Comment: @vallentin, so my confusion was that it worked in my initial solution, where I collected the result of the map first, and then made it into an iterator again with `iter` to be used by `flat_map`. But then I wasn't sure why couldn't just remove the one `collect` and `iter` and merge the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to use `flat_map` specifically? If not, it would be done like this:

```rust
fn capitalize_words_strings(words: &[&str]) -> String {
    words.iter()
        .map(|word| capitalize_first(word))
        .collect()
}
```

If you really need to use `flat_map`, you can just add a "noop" `flat_map` by doing `std::iter::once()`.

```rust
fn capitalize_words_strings(words: &[&str]) -> String {
    words.iter()
        .map(|word| capitalize_first(word))
        .flat_map(|word| std::iter::once(word))
        .collect()
}
```